# Re encode json after file manipulation

Tags: php, json, file-io

I'm having some problems re-encoding the json back to it's format. What I'm trying to achieve is, on a .json file upload, modify it to meet certain standards.

The problem is when I try to modify the image src on the file an encode it back to json, nevertheless the array in the foreach loop prints out correctly, the new file is generated without any content!

Glad if you could give me a little help over this one

```
function prepareImages($file,$url,$article)
{

    $string = file_get_contents($file);
    $json = json_decode($string,true);
    $value = array();
    //$array = $json['elements'];
            //$imgArray = array();
    /* if(['type'] == "image")
    {
        array_push($json['elements']['src'],$array);
    } */

    foreach($json['elements'] as $value)
    {
        if($value['type'] == "image")
        {
                        $arr = explode('\\', $value['src']);
                        $count = count($arr);
                        $img = $arr[$count-1];
                        $src = $url.'res/'.$article.'/'.$img;
                        $value['src'] = $src;

                        //print_r($json);
        }
                    //This prints all the values correctly
                    print_r($value);


    } 
                    $json = $value;
                    $string = json_encode($json);

            file_put_contents($file,$string);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) documentation, that function escapes forward slashes, try doing this:

```
$value['src'] = str_replace('\\/', '/', $src)
```

Comment: The problem is not with character escaping but the generated .json file is empty!

Comment: what does echoing $string return?

Comment: file_put_contents will return false if it failed, or number of butes changed when successful. what does it return?

Comment: This is what I get from file_put_contents "File upload successfuly 158"

Comment: could another script be overwriting this file? file_put_contents doesn't check if the string is empty, try adding if (!empty($string)) {  file_put_contents($file,$string); } and see if this is still happening.

Comment: I think the problem is with the loop itself. I'll need to run over it